# How to change spaces before and after sections and chapters

Tags: spacing, document-classes

I am using this [documentclass](https://github.com/MohaVall/classe/blob/master/aesm_edspia1.cls) with option `[twoside,12pt]` and this MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{Classes/aesm_edspia1}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}%font modern
\rmfamily
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * cmr/bx/sc}{} %manque une police en lmodern
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epsfig, floatflt, amssymb}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}%figure entouré de texte.
\usepackage{moreverb} %% pour le verbatim en boite
\usepackage{cases}%equations en systemes numérotés - soluce possible package : CASES
%\usepackage{slashbox} %% pour couper les colonnes des tableaux en diagonale
%\usepackage{layout}
%\usepackage{showkeys} %% pour voir les labels
\usepackage{multirow} %% pour regrouper un texte sur plusieurs lignes dans une table
\usepackage{url} %% pour citer les url par \url
\usepackage[all]{xy} %% pour la barre au dessus des symboles
%\usepackage{shorttoc} %% pour plusieurs tables des matières par la commande \shorttableofcontents{Titre}{profondeur}.
\usepackage{textcomp} %% pour le symbol pour mille par \textperthousand et degrés par \degres
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\usepackage{setspace} %interligne simple, double etc...
\usepackage{eurosans} %%pour le symbole \euro
\usepackage{epic,eepic}
\usepackage{soul}
%\usepackage{lineno}%numéroter les lignes
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % tables des figures, des matieres et autres dans la TOC
%\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[leftcaption]{sidecap}
%\usepackage[labelsep=endash, textfont={normalsize,onehalfspacing}, margin=5pt, format=hang, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash, textfont={footnotesize, singlespacing}, margin=10pt, format=plain, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} %en tete chapitrage
\newcommand{\ie}{c.-\`a-d.~}
\hbadness=10000% pb d'overfull box réglé
\hfuzz=50pt
\pdfcompresslevel9 % pour compresser le pdf final au maximum
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=5 % pour accepté les images PDF version 1.5 (ex: celles produites par Office 2007)
\def\underscore{\char`\_}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic {section}}
\renewcommand{\SC@figure@vpos}{c}% centrer verticalement le caption avec le package sidecap...
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\small\textbf{Figure~\thefigure}}
\renewcommand{\fnum@table}{\small\textbf{Tableau~\thetable}}
%\newcommand\figcaption{\def\@captype{figure}\caption}
%\newcommand\tabcaption{\def\@captype{table}\caption}
\makeatother
\usepackage{subfig}
\def\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\def\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{here}
%\newlength\longest
\usepackage{pifont}
\input{tcilatex}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\figurename{\small\textbf{Figure}}

\addtocounter{page}{-1}%pour revenir à 0



\makethese %% crée la couverture.

\onehalfspacing


\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Introduction }
%\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
%\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~\thechapter. #1 }}{}}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thechapter.\thesection~ #1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter*{Introduction g\'en\'erale}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction générale}
%==================================================================================================%
Dans ce chapitre, nous allons parler des
g\'{e}n\'{e}ralit\'{e}s sur la
SUSY. Nous commencerons par la description de l'alg\`{e}bre supersym\'{e}%
trique, ensuite nous allons donner ses repr\'{e}sentations. Et
finalement on va parler des superespaces et
superchamps.

\section{Mod\`{e}le particulier avec une vari\'{e}t\'{e} hyper-K\"{a}%
hlerienne et un groupe de jauge $U(1)\times U(1)$}

Dans les parties pr\'{e}c\'{e}dentes, on a vu que ce mod\`{e}le
contient un multiplet de mati\`{e}re d\'{e}crit par un multiplet
tensoriel ou un hyper-multiplet, et $n$ superchamps de Maxwell
$U(1)$. Dor\'{e}navant on va
le restreindre par l'imposition du potentiel de K\"{a}hler suivant:%
\begin{equation}
K\left( Q^{u},\overline{Q}^{\overline{u}}\right) =\overline{Q}^{1}Q^{1}+%
\overline{Q}^{2}Q^{2}=\left( \overline{Q}^{1}\text{ }Q^{1}\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1%
\end{pmatrix}%
\binom{Q^{1}}{Q^{2}}.  \label{20}
\end{equation}%
On remarque que la m\'{e}trique de K\"{a}hler est Ricci-plate, on a
aussi
chang\'{e} les notations de deux multiplet chiral de l'hypermultiplet: $%
\left( \overline{Q}^{1},\text{ }Q^{1}\right) .$ le mod\`{e}le dual \`{a} (\ref%
{17}) avec le potentiel de K\"{a}hler particulier (\ref{20}):%
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{L} &\mathcal{=}&\mathcal{L}_{gauge}+\dint d^{4}\theta
\left[
\overline{Q}^{1}e^{-2g_{a}V^{a}}Q^{1}+\overline{Q}^{2}e^{2g_{a}V^{a}}Q^{2}%
\right]  \label{21} \notag \\
&&+\dint d^{2}\theta \left[ \left( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}X^{a}\right) Q^{1}Q^{2}-%
\frac{ig_{a}}{k_{a}}Y\right] , \label{21}
\end{eqnarray}%
o\`{u} $m$ est un param\`{e}tre de masse, et $Q^{1}$ et $Q^{2}$ ont
deux charges de $U(1)$ opos\'{e}es.\newline Pour determiner $H\left(
L,\Phi ,\overline{\Phi }\right) $, on doit effectuer une
transformation de dualit\'{e} inverse, pour ceci on doit faire
le changement de variables suivant:%
\begin{equation}
Q^{1}=\sqrt{\frac{\Phi }{\sqrt{2}}}e^{-\Phi \prime
},Q^{2}=i\sqrt{\frac{\Phi
}{\sqrt{2}}}e^{\Phi \prime }\  \  \Rightarrow Q^{1}Q^{2}=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}%
\Phi .  \label{tfn}
\end{equation}%
Alors (\ref{21}) devient:%
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{L} &\mathcal{=}&\mathcal{L}_{gauge}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\dint
d^{4}\theta \sqrt{\overline{\Phi }\Phi }\left[ e^{\overline{\Phi
}\prime +\Phi \prime +2g_{a}V^{a}}+e^{-\overline{\Phi }\prime -\Phi
\prime
-2g_{a}V^{a}}\right] \\
&&+\dint d^{2}\theta \left( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}X^{a}\right) \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}%
\Phi -\frac{ig_{a}}{k_{a}}Y+h.c.
\end{eqnarray*}%
Le potentiel de K\"{a}hler depend maintenant de $\overline{\Phi
}\prime
+\Phi \prime ,$ alors le model dual \`{a} (\ref{21}) est donn\'{e} par:%
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{L} &\mathcal{=}&\mathcal{L}_{gauge}+\dint d^{4}\theta H\left( L,\Phi ,%
\overline{\Phi }\right) +\dint d^{2}\theta \left( m+\sqrt{2}%
ig_{a}X^{a}\right) \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\Phi  \label{24} \\
&&-\frac{ig_{a}}{k_{a}}Y+h.c,  \notag
\end{eqnarray}%
avec:%
\begin{equation}
H\left( L,\Phi ,\overline{\Phi }\right) =\sqrt{L^{2}+2\Phi \overline{\Phi }}%
-L\ln \left( L+\sqrt{L^{2}+2\Phi \overline{\Phi }}\right)
+2g_{a}LV^{a}. \label{25}
\end{equation}%
En effet:%
\begin{equation}
\dint d^{4}\theta \sqrt{\frac{\overline{\Phi }\Phi }{2}}\left[ e^{\overline{%
\Phi }\prime +\Phi \prime +2g_{a}V^{a}}+e^{-\overline{\Phi }\prime
-\Phi \prime -2g_{a}V^{a}}\right] ,  \label{dl1}
\end{equation}%
est \'{e}quivalant \`{a}\footnote{%
En \'{e}limiant L dans (\ref{dl2}), par son \'{e}quation du
mouvement, on trouve facilement (\ref{dl1})}:
\begin{equation}
\dint d^{4}\theta \left[ \sqrt{\frac{\overline{\Phi }\Phi
}{2}}\left[ e^{A}+e^{-A}\right] -L\left( A-2g_{a}V^{a}\right)
\right] ,  \label{dl2}
\end{equation}%
o\`{u} $A$ est un superchamp arbitraire r\'{e}el et $L$ est un superchamp lin%
\'{e}aire qui joue le r\^{o}le d'un multiplicateur de Lagrange.
L'\'{e}quation du mouvement de A implique:%
\[
\sqrt{\frac{\overline{\Phi }\Phi }{2}}\left( e^{A}-e^{-A}\right)
-L=0,
\]%
dont la solution est:%
\begin{equation}
e^{A}=\frac{L}{\sqrt{2\left\vert \Phi \right\vert ^{2}}}\left( L+\sqrt{%
L^{2}+2\left\vert \Phi \right\vert ^{2}}\right) .  \label{dl3}
\end{equation}%
En substituant (\ref{dl3}) dans (\ref{dl2}) on trouve:%
\[
\dint d^{4}\theta \left[ \sqrt{L^{2}+2\left\vert \Phi \right\vert
^{2}}-L\ln
\left( L+\sqrt{L^{2}+2\left\vert \Phi \right\vert ^{2}}\right) +2Lg_{a}V^{a}%
\right]+un\,terme\,de\,surface =\dint d^{4}\theta H\left( L\right).
\]%
\ Il est maintenant simple de v\'{e}rifier que $H\left( L,\Phi ,\overline{%
\Phi }\right) $ satisfait l'\'{e}quation de Laplace. Le lagrangien
(\ref{21}) depend d'un champ 4-forme $Y$ mais son \'{e}quation de
mouvement pose la
contrainte suivante:%
\begin{equation}
\frac{g_{a}}{k_{a}}=0.  \label{26}
\end{equation}%
Alors la d\'{e}pendance du champ non dynamique $Y$ est
\'{e}limin\'{e}e grace \`{a} la contrainte (\ref{26}).\newline
Remarque: dans le cas d'un seul $U(1)$ la contrainte (\ref{26}) devient: $%
\frac{g}{k}=0$, alors soit l'hypermultiplet est non charg\'{e} sous
$U(1)$ $\left( g=0\right) $, ou la seconde SUSY est r\'{e}alis\'{e}e
lin\'{e}airement $\left( \frac{1}{k}=0\right) $, et
dans les deux cas on peut pas bris\'{e}e la SUSY $\mathcal{N}=2$ \`{a} deux \'{e}chelles diff%
\'{e}rentes.

\section{Vide du mod\`{e}le}

Comme ce mod\`{e}le contient un hypermultiplet $\left( 0^{4},\frac{1}{2}%
^{2}\right) $ et un multiplet de Maxwell $\left( 0^{2},\frac{1}{2}%
^{2},1\right) $ alors on a deux phases; la phase de Higgs qui est associ\'{e}%
e \`{a} l'hypermultiplet et dans laquelle le groupe de jauge
$U(1)\times U(1) $ est intact \cite{1}, et celle de Coulomb qui est
associ\'{e}e \`{a} le multiplet de Maxwell et dans laquelle le
groupe de jauge $U(1)\times U(1)$ est bris\'{e}. on remarque qu'on
ne peut utiliser dans la phase de Coulomb que le formalisme
d'hypermultiplet, car si $U(1)\times U(1)$ est intact
alors la valeur moyenne dans le vide ( VEV\ ) des champs scalaires $%
\left \langle q^{u}\right \rangle \ $est nulle, mais la
d\'{e}finition des champs (\ref{tfn}) montre que $\left \langle
q^{u}\right \rangle $ ne peut pas \^{e}tre nul, par cons\'{e}quent
on peut utiliser le formalisme tensoriel seulement dans la phase de
Higgs, mais l'analyse de cette branche est plus simple si on utilise
le formalisme tensoriel.

\subsection{Phase de Coulomb}

Comme ce qu'on a vu, dans le formalisme d'hypermultiplet le
lagrangien est
donn\'{e} par (\ref{21}) \cite{1}:%
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{L} &\mathcal{=}&\dint d^{4}\theta \left( \overline{Q}%
^{1}e^{-2g_{a}V^{a}}Q^{1}+\overline{Q}^{2}e^{2g_{a}V^{a}}Q^{2}\right)
+\dint
d^{4}\theta \xi _{a}V^{a} \\
&&+\frac{i}{2}\dint d^{4}\theta \left[
\overline{\mathcal{F}}_{a}\left(
\overline{X}^{b}\right) X^{a}-\mathcal{F}_{a}\left( X^{b}\right) \overline{X}%
^{a}\right] \\
&&+\dint d^{2}\theta \left( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}X^{a}\right) Q^{1}Q^{2}+h.c-%
\frac{i}{4}\dint d^{2}\theta \mathcal{F}_{ab}\left( X^{c}\right)
W^{a}W^{b}+h.c \\
&&-\dint d^{2}\theta \left( \frac{e}{4}X^{a}+\frac{i}{4k_{a}}\mathcal{F}%
_{a}\left( X^{b}\right) \right) +h.c.
\end{eqnarray*}%
Le potentiel scalaire est donn\'{e} par \cite{WB}:%
\begin{equation*}
V_{s}=\overline{F}^{\overline{q}^{1}}F^{q^{1}}+\overline{F}^{\overline{q}%
^{2}}F^{q^{2}}+h^{ab}\overline{F}^{\overline{x}^{a}}F^{x^{b}}+\frac{1}{2}%
h^{ab}D_{a}D_{b}.
\end{equation*}%
Calculons les expressions de $\overline{F}^{\overline{q}^{1}}$et $\overline{F%
}^{\overline{q}^{2}}$:%
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tabular}{l}
$\dint d^{4}\theta \left( \overline{Q}^{\overline{1}}e^{-2g_{a}V^{a}}Q^{1}%
\right) +\dint d^{2}\theta \left( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}X^{a}\right)
Q^{1}Q^{2}+h.c $ \\
$=\dint d^{4}\theta \left[ \overline{Q}^{\overline{1}}\left(
1-2g_{a}V^{a}+...\right) Q^{1}\right] +\dint d^{2}\theta \left( m+\sqrt{2}%
ig_{a}X^{a}\right) Q^{1}Q^{2}+h.c,$ \\
$\supset \dint d^{4}\theta \left[ \left( \overline{\theta }^{2}\overline{F}^{%
\overline{q}^{1}}\right) \left( 1\right) \left( \theta ^{2}F^{q^{1}}\right) %
\right] +\dint d^{2}\theta \left( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}x^{a}\right)
\left( \theta
^{2}F^{q^{1}}\right) q^{2}+h.c,$ \\
$=\overline{F}^{\overline{q}^{1}}F^{q^{1}}+\left( m+\sqrt{2}%
ig_{a}x^{a}\right) F^{q^{1}}q^{2}+h.c.$%
\end{tabular}%
\end{equation*}%
Alors l'\'{e}quation de mouvement de $F^{q^{1}}$:%
\begin{equation*}
\overline{F}^{\overline{q}^{1}}+\left( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}x^{a}\right)
q^{2}=0\Rightarrow \overline{F}^{q^{1}}=-\left(
m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}x^{a}\right) q^{2}=-m_{eff}q^{2},
\end{equation*}%
avec%
\begin{equation*}
m_{eff}=m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}x^{a}.
\end{equation*}

\begin{itemize}
\item
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\dint d^{4}\theta \left(
\overline{Q}^{2}e^{2g_{a}V^{a}}Q^{2}\right)
+\dint d^{2}\theta \left( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}X^{a}\right) Q^{1}Q^{2}+h.c \\
&=&\dint d^{4}\theta \left[ \overline{Q}^{2}\left(
1+2g_{a}V^{a}+...\right) Q^{2}\right] +\dint d^{2}\theta \left(
m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}X^{a}\right)
Q^{1}Q^{2}+h.c, \\
&\supset &\dint d^{4}\theta \left[ \left( \overline{\theta }^{2}\overline{F}%
^{\overline{q}^{2}}\right) \left( 1\right) \left( \theta
^{2}F^{q^{2}}\right) \right] +\dint d^{2}\theta \left( m+\sqrt{2}%
ig_{a}x^{a}\right) \left( \theta ^{2}F^{q^{2}}\right) q^{1}+h.c, \\
&=&\overline{F}^{\overline{q}^{2}}F^{q^{2}}+\left( m+\sqrt{2}%
ig_{a}x^{a}\right) F^{q^{2}}q^{1}+h.c.
\end{eqnarray*}%
Alors l'\'{e}quation de mouvement de $F^{q^{2}}$:%
\begin{equation*}
\overline{F}^{\overline{q}^{2}}+\left( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}x^{a}\right)
q^{1}=0\Rightarrow \overline{F}^{\overline{q}^{2}}=-\left( m+\sqrt{2}%
ig_{a}x^{a}\right) q^{1}=-m_{eff}q^{1}.
\end{equation*}%
Calcul de $F^{x^{a}}:$
\item
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
$\frac{i}{2}\dint d^{4}\theta \left( \overline{F}_{a}X^{a}-F_{a}\overline{X}%
^{a}\right) $ & $=$ & $\frac{i}{2}\dint d^{4}\theta \left( \overline{F}_{ba}%
\overline{X}^{b}X^{a}-F_{ba}X^{b}\overline{X}^{a}\right) ,$ \\
&  & $\supset \frac{i}{2}\dint d^{4}\theta \left[
\overline{F}_{ba}\left( \overline{\theta
}^{2}\overline{F}^{\overline{x}^{b}}\right) \left( \theta
^{2}F^{x^{a}}\right) -F_{ba}\left( \theta ^{2}F^{x^{b}}\right)
\left(
\overline{\theta }^{2}\overline{F}^{\overline{x}^{a}}\right) \right] ,$ \\
&  & $=\frac{i}{2}\left[ \overline{F}_{ba}\overline{F}^{\overline{x}%
^{b}}F^{x^{a}}-F_{ba}F^{x^{b}}\overline{F}^{\overline{x}^{a}}\right] .$%
\end{tabular}%
\end{equation*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I have a huge space before sections and after chapters.I tried to use `\vspace` but it does not work perfectly i.e it either leaves a huge space or causes text overlapping. So my question is how to fix the space between and after each section, subsection and after each chapter too?

N.B: I tried in vain to use the `titlesec` package.

Comment: `fancyhdr` is actually not responsible for the space before chapters, that's the work of the document class

Comment: You shouldn't use the code posted before *each* chapter but once in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @Johannes_B is this a remark to make things more easy or this effects the spaces ?

Comment: As Christian said, this has nothing to do with the spacing.

Comment: The code you show is unrelated to the space around the chapter heading, it should not be in the document body at all but sets the page header for the whole document, in the preamble. Make a small complete document that shows the problem, then someone will be able to suggest some code.

Comment: the class doesn't appear to change the chapter or section headings, it just uses tech standard `book` class definitions so you should be able to demonstrate your problem just using `\documentclass{book}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for your comment. I added a long WE to show the problem.

Comment: `\hbadness=10000% pb d'overfull box réglé
\hfuzz=50pt` really????? This basically tells TeX that you really don't care how bad the output is, why do you have these lines?  Are you using scientific word? if not why input tcilatex? also don't use here or epsfig packages.

Comment: If I change the class to `book` and ifgnore the undefined commands and files that I don't have (tcilatex.tex and eurosand.sty) the result looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sqAGn.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, in fact I wrote this dissertation before three years, I used Scientific Word since I did not yet become familiar with LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your LaTeX code isn't exactly easy to parse, it's quite inefficient in various places, and it uses environments such as `eqnarray` that are *badly deprecated* and for which there is no longer any justification for their continued use. I've tried to clean up your code (quite) a bit. As a side-effect of this clean-up, the large gaps above and below some of the section headers are gone. Please take the time to study how the cleaned-up code differs from the original code, and please draw your own conclusions as to the changes you should make in your coding practices going forward.

The following screenshot shows the page numbered "3" (out of 7 pages); note the absence of excessive space above and below the section header "2 Vide du modèle".

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,demo]{aesm_edspia}
   % remove 'demo' option in real document

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{lmr}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * cmr/bx/sc}{} 
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{floatflt, amssymb}
\usepackage{moreverb} %% pour le verbatim en boite
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url} %% pour citer les url par \url
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{epic,eepic}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[leftcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash, textfont={footnotesize, singlespacing}, 
     margin=10pt, format=plain, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} %en tete chapitrage
\newcommand{\ie}{c.-à-d.~}
%%%%\hbadness=10000% pb d'overfull box réglé
%%%%\hfuzz=50pt
%%%%\pdfcompresslevel9 % pour compresser le pdf final au maximum
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=5 % pour accepter les images PDF version 1.5 (ex: celles produites par Office 2007)
\def\underscore{\char`\_}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\SC@figure@vpos}{c}% centrer verticalement le caption avec le package sidecap...
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\small\textbf{Figure~\thefigure}}
\renewcommand{\fnum@table}{\small\textbf{Tableau~\thetable}}
%\newcommand\figcaption{\def\@captype{figure}\caption}
%\newcommand\tabcaption{\def\@captype{table}\caption}
\makeatother

\usepackage{subfig}
\def\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
%%%\def\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage{float}
%%%%\usepackage{here}
\newlength\longest
\usepackage{pifont}
%%%%\input{tcilatex}
\newcommand{\dint}{\displaystyle\int} % ? do make sure that this is the correct definition

\renewcommand\figurename{\small\textbf{Figure}}


\begin{document}


\addtocounter{page}{-1}%pour revenir à 0


\makethese %% crée la couverture.

\onehalfspacing


\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Introduction }
%\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
%\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\chapter*{Introduction générale}    
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction générale}

Dans ce chapitre, nous allons parler des
généralités sur la
SUSY. Nous commencerons par la description de l'algèbre supersymétrique, 
ensuite nous allons donner ses représentations. Et
finalement on va parler des superespaces et
superchamps.

\section{Modèle particulier avec une variété hyper-Kählerienne 
et un groupe de jauge $U(1)\times U(1)$}

Dans les parties précédentes, on a vu que ce modèle
contient un multiplet de matière décrit par un multiplet
tensoriel ou un hyper-multiplet, et $n$ superchamps de Maxwell
$U(1)$. Dorénavant on va
le restreindre par l'imposition du potentiel de Kähler suivant:
\begin{equation} \label{20}
K( Q^{u},\bar{Q}^{\bar{u}}) =\bar{Q}^{1}Q^{1}+\bar{Q}^{2}Q^{2}
=\begin{pmatrix} \bar{Q}^{1} & Q^{2} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} Q^{1} \\ Q^{2} \end{pmatrix}. 
\end{equation}
On remarque que la métrique de Kähler est Ricci-plate, on a aussi
changé les notations de deux multiplet chiral de l'hypermultiplet: 
$\begin{pmatrix} \bar{Q}^{1} & Q^{2} \end{pmatrix}$ 
le modèle dual à \eqref{17} avec le potentiel de Kähler particulier~\eqref{20}:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L} &= \mathcal{L}_{\textrm{gauge}}+\dint d^{4}\theta
\left[
\bar{Q}^{1}e^{-2g_{a}V^{a}}Q^{1}+\bar{Q}^{2}e^{2g_{a}V^{a}}Q^{2}%
\right]  \notag \\
&\quad+\dint d^{2}\theta \left[ ( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}X^{a}) Q^{1}Q^{2}-
\frac{ig_{a}}{k_{a}}Y\right] , \label{21}
\end{align}
où $m$ est un paramètre de masse, et $Q^{1}$ et $Q^{2}$ ont
deux charges de $U(1)$ oposées.

Pour determiner $H(L,\Phi ,\bar{\Phi }) $, on doit effectuer une
transformation de dualité inverse, pour ceci on doit faire
le changement de variables suivant:
\begin{equation} \label{tfn}
Q^{1}=\sqrt{\frac{\Phi }{\sqrt{2}}}e^{-\Phi '
},\quad
Q^{2}=i\sqrt{\frac{\Phi
}{\sqrt{2}}}e^{\Phi ' } \quad
\Rightarrow \quad
Q^{1}Q^{2}=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\Phi .  
\end{equation}
Alors \eqref{21} devient:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L} &= \mathcal{L}_{\textrm{gauge}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\dint
d^{4}\theta \sqrt{\bar{\Phi }\Phi }\left[ e^{\bar{\Phi}' +\Phi ' 
+2g_{a}V^{a}}+e^{-\bar{\Phi }' -\Phi' -2g_{a}V^{a}}\right] \\
&\quad+\dint d^{2}\theta ( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}X^{a}) \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\Phi -\frac{ig_{a}}{k_{a}}Y+h.c.
\end{align*}
Le potentiel de Kähler depend maintenant de $\bar{\Phi}'+\Phi'$, 
alors le model dual à~\eqref{21} est donné par:
\begin{equation} \label{24}
\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{L}_{\textrm{gauge}}+\dint d^{4}\theta H( L,\Phi ,\bar{\Phi }) +
\dint d^{2}\theta ( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}X^{a}) \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\Phi  -\frac{ig_{a}}{k_{a}}Y+h.c, 
\end{equation}
avec:
\begin{equation} \label{25}
H( L,\Phi ,\bar{\Phi }) =\sqrt{L^{2}+2\Phi \bar{\Phi }}
-L\ln \bigl( L+\sqrt{L^{2}+2\Phi \bar{\Phi }}\,\bigr)
+2g_{a}LV^{a}. 
\end{equation}%
En effet:%
\begin{equation}\label{dl1}
\dint d^{4}\theta \sqrt{\frac{\bar{\Phi }\Phi }{2}}\left[ e^{\bar{\Phi }' +\Phi ' 
+2g_{a}V^{a}}+e^{-\bar{\Phi }'
-\Phi ' -2g_{a}V^{a}}\right] ,  
\end{equation}
est équivalant à\footnote{En élimiant L dans \eqref{dl2}, par son équation du
mouvement, on trouve facilement \eqref{dl1}}:
\begin{equation} \label{dl2}
\dint d^{4}\theta \left[ \sqrt{\frac{\bar{\Phi }\Phi}{2}}[ e^{A}+e^{-A}] 
-L( A-2g_{a}V^{a}) \right] ,  
\end{equation}
où $A$ est un superchamp arbitraire réel et $L$ est un superchamp linéaire 
qui joue le r\^{o}le d'un multiplicateur de Lagrange.
L'équation du mouvement de $A$ implique:%
\[
\sqrt{\frac{\bar{\Phi }\Phi }{2}}( e^{A}-e^{-A}) -L=0,
\]
dont la solution est:
\begin{equation} \label{dl3}
e^{A}=\frac{L}{\sqrt{2\lvert \Phi \rvert ^{2}}}
\bigl( L+\sqrt{L^{2}+2\lvert \Phi \rvert ^{2}}\,\bigr) .  
\end{equation}
En substituant \eqref{dl3} dans \eqref{dl2} on trouve:
\[
\dint d^{4}\theta \left[ \sqrt{L^{2}+2\lvert \Phi \rvert
^{2}}
-L\ln\bigl( L+\sqrt{L^{2}+2\lvert \Phi \rvert ^{2}}\,\bigr) +2Lg_{a}V^{a}
\right]+\text{un terme de surface} 
=\dint d^{4}\theta H(L).
\]

Il est maintenant simple de vérifier que $H( L,\Phi ,\bar{\Phi })$ satisfait 
l'équation de Laplace. Le lagrangien
\eqref{21} dépend d'un champ 4-forme $Y$ mais son équation de
mouvement pose la contrainte suivante:
\begin{equation}\label{26}
\frac{g_{a}}{k_{a}}=0.  
\end{equation}
Alors la dépendance du champ non dynamique $Y$ est
éliminée grace à la contrainte~\eqref{26}.

Remarque: dans le cas d'un seul $U(1)$ la contrainte \eqref{26} devient: 
$\frac{g}{k}=0$, alors soit l'hypermultiplet est non chargé sous
$U(1)$ ($ g=0$), ou la seconde SUSY est réalisée
linéairement $\bigl( \frac{1}{k}=0\bigr) $, et
dans les deux cas on peut pas brisée la SUSY $\mathcal{N}=2$ 
à deux échelles différentes.

\section{Vide du modèle}

Comme ce modèle contient un hypermultiplet $( 0^{4},\frac{1}{2}^{2}) $ 
et un multiplet de Maxwell $( 0^{2},\frac{1}{2}^{2},1) $ alors on a 
deux phases; la phase de Higgs qui est associée à l'hypermultiplet et 
dans laquelle le groupe de jauge
$U(1)\times U(1) $ est intact \cite{1}, et celle de Coulomb qui est
associée à le multiplet de Maxwell et dans laquelle le
groupe de jauge $U(1)\times U(1)$ est brisé. on remarque qu'on
ne peut utiliser dans la phase de Coulomb que le formalisme
d'hypermultiplet, car si $U(1)\times U(1)$ est intact
alors la valeur moyenne dans le vide ( VEV ) des champs scalaires 
$\langle q^{u}\rangle$ est nulle, mais la
définition des champs \eqref{tfn} montre que $\langle q^{u}\rangle $ 
ne peut pas être nul, par conséquent
on peut utiliser le formalisme tensoriel seulement dans la phase de
Higgs, mais l'analyse de cette branche est plus simple si on utilise
le formalisme tensoriel.


\subsection{Phase de Coulomb}


Comme ce qu'on a vu, dans le formalisme d'hypermultiplet le
lagrangien est
donné par~\eqref{21} \cite{1}:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L} &= \dint d^{4}\theta ( \bar{Q}^{1}e^{-2g_{a}V^{a}}Q^{1}
+\bar{Q}^{2}e^{2g_{a}V^{a}}Q^{2})
+\dint
d^{4}\theta \xi _{a}V^{a} \\
&\quad+\frac{i}{2}\dint d^{4}\theta \left[
\bar{\mathcal{F}}_{a}(\bar{x}^{b}) X^{a}-\mathcal{F}_{a}( X^{b}) 
\bar{x}^{a}\right] \\
&\quad+\dint d^{2}\theta ( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}X^{a}) Q^{1}Q^{2}+h.c-
\frac{i}{4}\dint d^{2}\theta \mathcal{F}_{ab}( X^{c})
W^{a}W^{b}+h.c \\
&\quad-\dint d^{2}\theta \bigl( \frac{e}{4}X^{a}+\frac{i}{4k_{a}}
\mathcal{F}_{a}( X^{b}) \bigr) +h.c.
\end{align*}
Le potentiel scalaire est donné par \cite{WB}:
\begin{equation*}
V_{s}=\bar{F}^{\bar{q}^{1}}F^{q^{1}}+\bar{F}^{\bar{q}^{2}}
F^{q^{2}}+h^{ab}\bar{F}^{\bar{x}^{a}}F^{x^{b}}+
\frac{1}{2}h^{ab}D_{a}D_{b}.
\end{equation*}
Calculons les expressions de $\bar{F}^{\bar{q}^{1}}$ et $\bar{F}^{\bar{q}^{2}}$:
\begin{align*}
\dint &d^{4}\theta ( \bar{Q}^{\bar{1}} e^{-2g_{a}V^{a}}Q^{1}) +
\dint d^{2}\theta ( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}X^{a})
Q^{1}Q^{2}+h.c  \\
&=\dint d^{4}\theta \left[ \bar{Q}^{\bar{1}}(
1-2g_{a}V^{a}+\dotsb) Q^{1}\right] +\dint d^{2}\theta 
( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}X^{a}) Q^{1}Q^{2}+h.c, \\
&\supset \dint d^{4}\theta \left[ ( \bar{\theta }^{2}\bar{F}^{\bar{q}^{1}}) 
( 1) ( \theta ^{2}F^{q^{1}}) \right] +
\dint d^{2}\theta ( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}x^{a})
( \theta^{2}F^{q^{1}}) q^{2}+h.c, \\
&=\bar{F}^{\bar{q}^{1}}F^{q^{1}}+
( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}x^{a}) F^{q^{1}}q^{2}+h.c.
\end{align*}
Alors l'équation de mouvement de $F^{q^{1}}$:
\begin{equation*}
\bar{F}^{\bar{q}^{1}}+( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}x^{a})
q^{2}=0\Rightarrow \bar{F}^{q^{1}}=-(
m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}x^{a}) q^{2}=-m_{\textrm{eff}}q^{2},
\end{equation*}
avec
\begin{equation*}
m_{\textrm{eff}}=m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}x^{a}.
\end{equation*}

\begin{itemize}
\item
\begin{align*}
\dint &d^{4}\theta (\bar{Q}^{2}e^{2g_{a}V^{a}}Q^{2})
+\dint d^{2}\theta ( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}X^{a}) Q^{1}Q^{2}+h.c \\
&\dint d^{4}\theta \left[ \bar{Q}^{2}(1+2g_{a}V^{a}+\dotsb) Q^{2}\right] +
\dint d^{2}\theta (m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}X^{a})
Q^{1}Q^{2}+h.c, \\
&\supset \dint d^{4}\theta \left[ 
( \bar{\theta}^{2}\bar{F}^{\bar{q}^{2}}) ( 1 ) ( \theta
^{2}F^{q^{2}}) \right] +
\dint d^{2}\theta ( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}x^{a}) ( \theta ^{2}F^{q^{2}}) q^{1}+h.c, \\
&=\bar{F}^{\bar{q}^{2}}F^{q^{2}}+( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}x^{a}) F^{q^{2}}q^{1}+h.c.
\end{align*}
Alors l'équation de mouvement de $F^{q^{2}}$:
\begin{equation*}
\bar{F}^{\bar{q}^{2}}+( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}x^{a})
q^{1}=0\Rightarrow \bar{F}^{\bar{q}^{2}}=
-( m+\sqrt{2}ig_{a}x^{a}) q^{1}=
-m_{\textrm{eff}}q^{1}.
\end{equation*}
Calcul de $F^{x^{a}}$:
\item
\begin{align*}
\frac{i}{2}\dint d^{4}\theta ( \bar{F}_{a}X^{a}-F_{a}\bar{x}^{a}) &= 
\frac{i}{2}\dint d^{4}\theta ( \bar{F}_{ba}
\bar{x}^{b}X^{a}-F_{ba}X^{b}\bar{x}^{a}) ,\\
&\supset \frac{i}{2}\dint d^{4}\theta \left[
\bar{F}_{ba}( \bar{\theta}^{2}\bar{F}^{\bar{x}^{b}}) 
( \theta^{2}F^{x^{a}}) -F_{ba}( \theta ^{2}F^{x^{b}})
(\bar{\theta}^{2}\bar{F}^{\bar{x}^{a}}) \right] , \\
&=\frac{i}{2}\left[ \bar{F}_{ba}\bar{F}^{\bar{x}^{b}}
F^{x^{a}}-F_{ba}F^{x^{b}}\bar{F}^{\bar{x}^{a}}\right] .
\end{align*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're right; but there is a problem of spaces in this thesis' template even when I modify the equations

Comment: @LlavDem - "There is a problem of spaces" is not very helpful. Please be (a lot) more specific.

Comment: I will replace the `eqnarray`s by `equation`s followed by `split`s in the whole document and then tell you if this solve the problem.

Comment: @LlavDem - Replacing `eqnarray` environments with `equation`/`split` combinations may not accomplish your objective of getting rid of the occasional big gaps around sectioning headers. There's a reason why my answer uses `align` (or `align*`) environments, coupled with the directive `\allowdisplaybreaks`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It solves the problem... I did not know the possibility of breaking equations.